# unable to ssl connect to chef-server from chef-workstation

Tags: ssl, chef-infra, knife

I have 2 different ubuntu VPS instances each with different ip addresses.
One is assigned as a chef-server and the other acts as a workstation.

When I use the command 
    knife configure -i

I do get options to locate admin.pem and chf-validator.pem files locally. 
I am also able to create knife.rb file locally.

WHile setting up knife, I get a question which asks me to enter 'chef-server url' so I enter 'https://ip_address/ of the vps instance

But in the end I get an error message

ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: "ip_address of my server host"- hostname "ip_address of my host" does not match the server certificate
ERROR: Could not establish a secure connection to the server.
Use `knife ssl check` to troubleshoot your SSL configuration.
If your Chef Server uses a self-signed certificate, you can use
`knife ssl fetch` to make knife trust the server's certificates.

I used 'knife ssl fetch' to fetch the trusted_certs from the chef-server but still it doesnt work.

CHef experts please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your chef-server has a hostname, the selfsigned certificate is done with this hostname.

The error you get is due to the fact you call an IP adress where the certificate is done for a hostname.

Two way: disable ssl validation (you'll have a warning but it will works) or make a configuration (using your hostname files for exemple) to use the chef-server hostname instead of ip address.

This is a SSL configuration point you may have with other servers too.